# What are functions within functions called in Python?

Tags: python

This is going to be a very n00b question...

In python, I want to write some functions to retrieve software version and system uptime for a few different types of devices. I could just write one function for each requirement, but I don't want to do it that way. I want to write functions within functions, so I could call them with dotted notation.

Below is an example of the functions I wish to create:

```
get(device)   # Determine device type and get software version and uptime
get.version(device)   # Determine device type and get software version 
get.uptime(device)    # Determine device type and get device up time
get.cisco.version(device)   # Get software version for a Cisco device
get.cisco.uptime(device)   # Get device up time for a Cisco device
get.arris.version(device)   # Get software version for an Arris device
get.arris.uptime(device)   # Get device up time for an Arris device
get.motorola.version(device)   # Get software versino for a Motorola device
get.motorola.uptime(device)   # Get device up time for a Motorola device
```

So, I would write a "get" function, and within that I would write a "version", "uptime", "cisco", "arris" and "motorola" function. Within these functions I would write more functions.

What is this called in Python? How is it implemented? I just need to know what I'm looking for so I can find it in the documentation and learn.

Comment: They're called "nested" functions, or sometimes "local" functions.

Comment: You can't actually nest functions in python, not properly. If you try it on the python console, you'll find that trying to access a nested function from outside the outerfunction yields an AttributeError.

Comment: x/y problem: seems like you could do this using classes & functions belonging to the class(es). In this case maybe look at the `abc.AbstractBaseClass` and have several classes (cisco, arris, etc.) that inherit from your abstract implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualizing these as nested method declarations is kind of weird, and that doesn't properly work in python unless you use lambdas, which are limiting. This is the type of functionality you would normally use classes for, because nesting those *does* work. So let's implement this as classes! The only snag is that `get()` will need to be kind of hacky to make it work the way you want it to, but we can work around that.

```
class get:
    # inner class cisco
    class cisco:
        @staticmethod
        def version(device):
            # do stuff

        @staticmethod
        def uptime(device):
            # do stuff

    # inner class motorola
    class motorola:
        ...

    # inner class arris
    class arris:
        ...

    # and now we define the stuff for the get class itself
    # (after the inner classes, because we need them to be defined
    # before we refer to them in the below methods

    def __new__(cls, device):
        # this is *supposed* to return a new instance of a `get`. 
        # We can override that behavior and have it return other things when `get()` is invoked
        return (get.version(device), get.uptime(device))

    @staticmethod
    def version(device):
        # do stuff

    @staticmethod
    def uptime(device):
        # do stuff
```

This allows all of the following to act as expected:

```
get(device)
get.version(device)
get.cisco.uptime(device)
```

The downside is you have to write all those methods explicitly. If you're nesting classes like this, you can't use the class `get` as a superclass for `get.cisco` or `get.motorola` or something.

I also used `@staticmethod` above, which allows you to put a method inside a class without having it take the extra (implicit) `cls` or `self` parameter. You could replace

```
@staticmethod
def version(device)
```

with

```
@classmethod
def version(cls, device)
```

and it would act more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this, and terminology for these nested functions is dependent on how you do it. The most direct approach is to define the functions as lambdas:

```
a = lambda dev: "a"
a.b = lambda dev: "b"
a.b.c = lambda dev: "c"

print(a("foo"), a.b("bar"), a.b.c("baz"))
```

Output:

```
a b c
```

---

Here's a slightly less contrived example as proof of concept, although I'm making no claim that this is good design (I would imagine a nested dictionary would be preferable, and your "back end" (the dictionaries) should probably be organized differently even if you do attempt it like this).

```
devices = {"baz": "some device"}
versions = {
    "motorola": "morotola thing",
    "arris": "arris thing",
    "cisco": "cisco thing"
}
cisco_versions = {"foo": "cisco foo thing"}

get = lambda dev: devices[dev]
get.version = lambda dev: versions[dev]
get.cisco = lambda: ""
get.cisco.version = lambda dev: cisco_versions[dev]

print(get("baz"))
print(get.version("arris"))
print(get.cisco.version("foo"))
```

Output:

```
some device
arris thing
cisco foo thing
```

You can also use a class containing static methods and nested classes as suggested by [Green Cloak Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605412/6243352), but the [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) is still of dubious merit for the client either way. I think it's pretty safe to say it's not particularly Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested functions but that is not a good idea. You can just name the functions with a prefixname